# how to find all methods names which are used in log statements in java

Tags: java, intellij-idea, logging

The below is the example, How to find the java files which logging the function/class names in log statements.

```
log.error("ManagerServiceImpl : processDeviceMgrNotification - failed for device [{}] due to: ");
```

Could any one suggest me the proper search criteria to use in intellij to get above result.

Comment: If you have "Class : method" pattern in the logging you can try search by regex:
log.error\("[A-z0-9]+ : [A-z0-9]+

Comment: I got message as .... Bad pattern "log.error("[A-z0-9]+ : [A-z0-9]+": Unclosed group.

Comment: Did you insert the pattern in the "Find in files" dialog?
And chose the "regexp" search?

Comment: The regex must be `log.error\("[A-z0-9]+ : [A-z0-9]+` (note the backslash before the "(" - otherwise the ( is interpreted as start of a capturing group)